# How to position Divs in Angular components

Tags: html, css, angular, css-position, angular-components

I am creating a simple Angular application in which I want to place navbar on the left side.
The problem is that I've get navbar very easy, but when I try to deal with the content (which shall be right next to the navbar), it is always "under" my navbar. I was trying several things to change, but the CSS between components is not so understandable to me.

Going to the code, I've got:
My navbar, which is described by following 1 CSS class:

```
.navbar{
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
background-color: gray;
overflow: auto;
}
```

In app.component.html I define my navbar as the first element, and next is router-outlet, just like here:

```
<div>
<app-main-nav></app-main-nav>
</div>
<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The result looks like that:
[Content on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rApkN.png)

"(Welcome to) the Good Practice service!" sentence starts behind the navbar.

Do you have some tips how to position Divs related between components to avoid situations like this?

Answer (score 1):

have you added the css class to the div?

Comment: This answer could be developed further - but it was my first thought as well. From the code example it doesn't appear that the div containing app-main-nav has the class 'navbar'.

Comment: Well I haven't clearly shown that, but the .navbar class is added inside of the html of main-nav component. But when I'm trying to add .navbar class in app component the result is still the same. It's strange, because CSS classes are working well, but the div's are ignoring each other.